# Export list of all tables in PostgreSQL server, showing schema and db to CSV

Tags: postgresql

I'm looking at tidying up my PostgreSQL server as I currently have several databases and more schemas within them.

I'm hoping there is an easy way to export a list of all tables, with their respective schema and database to a csv (or similar). This would allow me to see an entire list of what is on the server and use it to see what's no longer needed.

I've tried looking around for an answer on stack but possibly don't know how to word it, so haven't found anything yet.

Is this possible and if so, how?

(I use PGAdmin and am running PostgreSQL 12 on a Windows environment)

Comment: `select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema <> 'pg_catalog'`?

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Can I post this as the answer with a couple of modifications (e.g. sticking the copy command on the front?)